# Finding radius of a non-uniform circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

A particle moves in a non-uniform circular motion.
At t1 = 2 s, the total acceleration is 6î + 4^j, and at t2 = 5 s, it is 4î - 6^j.
How can I find the radius of the trajectory?

I noticed that radial acceleration is |ar|= 4 m/s², and tangential acceleration is |aT|= 6 m/s². But how can I find the radius? I have the time interval of 3 seconds, and I think it travelled a 3π/2 arc.
I am lost with vectors.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: If the object is moving in a circle with a tangential acceleration, then the radial acceleration will not be constant. If it is not moving in a circle, then the radius will not be constant. We need clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that each acceleration has the same magnitude (7.2111). If the motion is uniform circular, then these would be the centripetal acceleration. The components give the directions which locate the object at two angular positions on the circle. Combined with the times, these give an angular velocity (two choices depending on the direction of motion). Then: R = $a_c/(ω^2)$.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was non-uniform. Thank you!